# Java 1.8.0_162, Drools 6.5.0 and Multiple Decision Tables (spreadsheets)

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am using Drools 6.5.0 with Java 1.8.0_162 and everything works properly with a single decision table (spreadsheet), see the code below:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession ks = kc.newKieSession("ksession-dtables");  //stateful knowledge session
FactHandle fh = ks.insert(fact);
ks.fireAllRules();
```

....

How do I dynamically and sequentially load and execute the rules of multiple decision tables?

In other words, load decision table #1 and execute its rules against the facts (data), when done load decision table #2 and execute its rules against the facts (data), when done load decision table #3 and execute its rules against the facts (data) and so forth until done processing all decision tables.  Dynamic, by placing all the decision tables in the same location (folder) in the classpath where the drools process can get and process.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!!

Comment: Add the error code also. Try creating a new Kiebase in your kmodule.xml and and  include the previous kiebase in the new Kiebase or add the new package to the KieBase. For example `<kbase name="KBase2"  packages="org.domain.pkg2, org.domain.pkg3" includes="KBase1"> <ksession name="KSession2_1" type="stateful" clockType="realtime"> </kbase>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using rule flow diagram. Add jBPM plugin and write a rule flow diagram.Add ks.startprocess("processId"); before fireAllRules().

Note: processId is the process id of rule flow diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in similar situation but instead of using Decision tables i was utilizing drl files of rules.
So first of all if you want to run all the rules to be run only once then use stateless kie-session instead of stateful.

```
        StatelessKieSession session = null;
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        session = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession("sessionIdentifier");
```

Once the rules inside this session are run the fact object is updated and you can process next set of rules with different sessionidentifier.

**stateless session having great performance benefit than stateful one. More of like use and throw.**

Running all the rules files (decision table) can be done by looping through all the session identifiers registered in kmodule.xml

Now in this case rules file are kept in resources folder.

But if you want to load them from filesystem, It is also achievable.